# Highcharts CSS Styling Axis Font

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have done a fair bit of reasearch but am stuck.  I am trying to format a high chart to have a text color of #75f094.  I have the following css code:

```
@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';

... Other CSS styling...

/* Highcharts Styling */
.highcharts-title {
    fill: #434348;
    color: #75f094;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.highcharts-subtitle {
    font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
    color: #75f094;
    font-style: italic;
    fill: #7cb5ec;
}

.highcharts-axis.highcharts-color-0 text {
    fill: #75f094;
}
```

and corresponding javascript code:

```
$(function() {

    var x_values = [];
    var y_values = [];
    var switch1 = true;
    $.get('php/values.php', function(data) {

        data = data.split('/');
        for (var i in data)
        {
            if (switch1 == true)
            {
                //var ts = timeConverter(data[i]);
                ts = (data[i]);
                //console.log(ts);
                x_values.push(ts);
                switch1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                y_values.push(parseFloat(data[i]));
                console.log(data[i]);
                switch1 = true;
            }

        }
        x_values.pop();

        $('#contentRight').highcharts({
            chart : {
                type : 'spline'
            },
            title : {
                text : 'Last 24hrs Usage'
            },
            subtitle : {
                text : 'Source: ESP8266db'
            },
            xAxis : {
                title : {
                    text : 'Time'
                },
                categories : x_values
            },
            yAxis : [{
                max: 100,
                className: 'highcharts-color-0',
                title : {
                    text : '% Light'
                },
                labels : {
                    formatter : function() {
                        return this.value + ' %'
                    }
                }
            }],
            tooltip : {
                crosshairs : true,
                shared : true,
                valueSuffix : ''
            },
            plotOptions : {
                spline : {
                    marker : {
                        radius : 4,
                        lineColor : '#666666',
                        lineWidth : 1
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
              enabled: false
            },
            series : [{

                name : 'Temperature',
                data : y_values
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

And it won't style the chart, it just colors as default.  The CSS is attached to the HTML page correctly as it is styling the rest of the page.  Any ideas where I am going wrong please? Browser is Chrome, not Firefox. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like highcharts uses SCSS to apply the axis colors as a style on the element.  So you can either update the neutral color in the SCSS:

`$neutral-color-60: #666666 !default; // Axis labels, axis title, connector fallback.`

or you can add the `!important` to your css style.  It uses both `color` and `fill` for the `highcharts-axis-title`, so it'd be:

```
.highcharts-axis-title {
  color: #75f094 !important;
  fill: #75f094 !important;
}
```